# Uploading content JSON gives null content

Tags: java, android, json, upload, contacts

I'm getting the contacts and put them into JSONArray to upload all of them to the server. When I extract them I'm creating a `Log.i();` and it shows the contacts correctly. But when I put the same value on a JSON array it says that it's null.

Here's the code:

```
    public void phoneandname(Context c) {

    if (cc.isOnline(c) == true) {
        db = new Database(c);

        Cursor phones = c.getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                null, null, null);

        JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray();
        db.open();

        while (phones.moveToNext()) {
            String name = phones
                    .getString(phones
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phoneNumber = phones
                    .getString(phones
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));


            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

            try {

                json.put("name", name);
                json.put("phone", phoneNumber);
                json.put("type", "insert");
                jarray.put(json);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

                ArrayList<NameValuePair> nvp = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    DBupload upload = new DBupload();
    DatosRegistro dr = new DatosRegistro(c);

    nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("content", String.valueOf(jarray)));
    nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token", dr.hash_final(
            dr.token_secret(dr.mail(), "mail"), jarray.toString())));
    nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", String.valueOf(dr
            .return_id_phone())));

    JSONObject json2 = upload.UploaData(nvp,
            "http://anonyme.mariomontes.es/contacts/insert");

    try {
        if (json2.getInt("error") == 1) {

        } else {
            db.contact_table(name, phoneNumber);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        db.close();

        Log.i("********", jarray.toString());
        phones.close();
    }

}
```

As you can see. I 'm showing the value and then I upload to the server. But it says it's that the content (the array) it's null and I don't know.

Comment: You upload jobject. What is that? You never populate it.

Comment: Sorry! Look it again please! :)